# Zapier Javascript code to isolate parts of a datetime string

Tags: javascript, zapier

I want to use the year, month, and day separately. First, I need to get rid of the time. Here's what I'm trying...

Input Data

datetime 2019-10-03 03:04:23

Code

```
let { datetime } = inputData;
let { date } = datetime.split(' ')[0];
const dateArray = date.split("-");
const year = dateArray[0];
const month = dateArray[1];
const day = dateArray[2];
output = [{year, month, day}];
```

The error I get is...

We had trouble sending your test through.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: At which line are you receiving that error? And is inputData a Date object or a String?

Comment: I can't tell what line it is. Zapier doesn't specify. I might not be here if it did.

I also can't tell whether inputData is a Date object or a string. I assume it's a string, but I can't prove it. It's being provided by Ninja forms.

Comment: If it's a string, why are you encapsulating the variable in curly braces when initializing it? Is it coming from within an object?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on this line:

```js
let { date } = datetime.split(' ')[0];
```

`datetime` is a string, so `datetime.split(' ')` returns `["2019-10-03", "03:04:23"]`. `["2019-10-03", "03:04:23"].date` is `undefined`, which is why the next line errors.

Remove those curly braces and it works as expected:

```js
let { datetime } = inputData;
let date = datetime.split(' ')[0]; // <-- change this line
const dateArray = date.split("-");
const year = dateArray[0];
const month = dateArray[1];
const day = dateArray[2];
output = [{year, month, day}];
```

Comment: I am assuming for both that datetime is the zapier defined inputdata var name (if its not then the user above will error out no matter what right? You could also replace lines 1 and 2 with `let date = inputData.datetime.split(' ')[0];`, I just do it that way to save myself a step.

Comment: correct, `inputData` has the input for the function